# Random Graphs in C

Tags: c, random, graph, probability

I have a homework about random graphs. I can't understand the question. Can anyone please clarify to me what I am supposed to do?

Let `N` be a positive integer and `p` be a number between 0 and 1. An `(N, p)` random graph is a graph generated by the following procedure:

Draw `N` vertices, denoted by `1, 2, . . . , N` respectively; for every pair `(u, v)` of
different vertices, with probability `p`, connect the two vertices with an edge. A graph is said to be connected if there is a path between any two vertices.

In this lab, you will write code to generate large random graphs and investigate the connectedness of such graphs.

We will fix `N` to be `500,000` but let p vary in `{0.05, 0.10, 0.15, ..., 0.95}`. For each value of p, you need to create 100 `(N, p)` random graphs. You need to develop a method (and of course implement it in your program) to determine if a graph is connected. Then for each value of p, you need to count the number `M` of random graphs that are connected, and investigate the relationship between `M` (which reflects the probability that a random graph is connected) and `p`.

Comment: What isn't clear, _exactly_?

Comment: I don't get what a random graph is. Is it just like a normal graph? If it is, I can't imagine how the vertices can be connected in more than one way.

Comment: From reading the quesiton it seems that once constructed it is a regular graph. It's the construction that has a non-deterministic element to it.

Answer (score 0):

A random graph is a graph that is randomly created:

#### Pseudo-code

```
for i := 1 to N
   for j := i+1 to N
       if bernoulli_distributed_with_param_p is true
           add undirected edge {i,j} to graph
```

The parameter `p` is simply the probability that two given vertices are connected. `bernoulli_distributed_with_param_p` is actually pretty simple to implement in C:

```
// Returns 0 with probability (1-p)
int bernoulli_distributed(double p){
    return (p > ((double)rand())/RAND_MAX);
}
```

Don't forget that you need to initialize the random generator with [`srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just gonna implement the function. One question: Why did you use a RAND_MAX instead of using modulo?

Comment: I solved the problem using your pseudocode, but it is taking forever. How can I solve it more efficiently? Keep in mind that N = 500,000.

Comment: @user1864733: **1.:** I divided by RAND_MAX to get a value between 0 and 1. **2.:** You can't. The algorithm itself has a lower bound of `Omega(n^2)`, because you need to check every pair, and there are `\sum_{i=1}^N N - i = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} i = (N - 1)(N - 2)/2` pairs. However, it is important that your data structure provides a mechanism to add an edge in constant time `(O(1))`, otherwise you'll get a even worse runtime complexity. Maybe you should add your graph data structure to your question.